# Could not open a connection to sql server

Tags: sql-server

i am running this in the command line:

```
sqlcmd -s .\SQLexpress
```

and the output i get is:

> HResult 0x2, Level 16, State 1
>   Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
>   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : A network-related or in
>   stance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server
>   . Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and i
>   f SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see
>    SQL Server Books Online..
>   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Login timeout expired.

when i run this:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe" -sSQLEXPRESS
```

i get: server error 17058 severity 16, state 1, could not open error log file

however this works:

```
osql -S .\SQLExpress -E
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is best suited to ServerFault / SuperUser.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Start -> Run, type "C:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe /32 "C:\Windows\system32\SQLServerManager.msc", then go to SQL Native Client Configuration, Client Protocols and check that shared memory, tcp/ip and named pipes are enabled.

Comment: ok, just go to Start \ Microsoft SQL Server 2005 \ Configuration Tools \ SQL Server Configuration Manager

Comment: ok, just replace 2005 to 2008 in my message. procesure is same.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

1)SQLServer Services / SQL Server PropertieS:  Logon as built-in account, LocalSystem

2)Check if all protocols for SQLEXPRESS are enabled
shared memory, named pipes and TCP/IP

3)SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration:  Client protocols:  Shared Memory, TCP/IP and Named Pipes all ENABLED

4)Added System Environment 
System > Advacned system settigns> Environmnet Settings>New
Variable Name: SQLCMDSERVER
Variable value: \SQLEXPRESS

Rob